# Call From 67a6fb652a0a/172.23.0.2 to 0.0.0.0:8032 failed on connection exception

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, geomesa

I built the jupyter/all-spark-notebook Docker image. I installed geomesa_pyspark and tried to run the following example commands from the official guide.

```
import geomesa_pyspark

conf = geomesa_pyspark.configure(
    jars=['/usr/local/spark/jars/geomesa-accumulo-spark-runtime_2.11-2.0.0.jar'],
    packages=['geomesa_pyspark','pytz'],
    spark_home='/usr/local/spark/').\
    setAppName('MyTestApp')

conf.get('spark.master')

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = ( SparkSession
    .builder
    .config(conf=conf)
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate()
)
```

I have this error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-cda5e93b8ec7> in <module>
     24 spark = ( SparkSession
     25     .builder
---> 26     .config(conf=conf)
     27     .enableHiveSupport()
     28     .getOrCreate()

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in getOrCreate(self)
    167                     for key, value in self._options.items():
    168                         sparkConf.set(key, value)
--> 169                     sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
    170                     # This SparkContext may be an existing one.
    171                     for key, value in self._options.items():

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/context.py in getOrCreate(cls, conf)
    332         with SparkContext._lock:
    333             if SparkContext._active_spark_context is None:
--> 334                 SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
    335             return SparkContext._active_spark_context
    336 

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/context.py in __init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls)
    116         try:
    117             self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,
--> 118                           conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
    119         except:
    120             # If an error occurs, clean up in order to allow future SparkContext creation:

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/context.py in _do_init(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
    178 
    179         # Create the Java SparkContext through Py4J
--> 180         self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
    181         # Reset the SparkConf to the one actually used by the SparkContext in JVM.
    182         self._conf = SparkConf(_jconf=self._jsc.sc().conf())

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/context.py in _initialize_context(self, jconf)
    271         Initialize SparkContext in function to allow subclass specific initialization
    272         """
--> 273         return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
    274 
    275     @classmethod

/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1399         answer = self._gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1400         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1401             answer, self._gateway_client, None, self._fqn)
   1402 
   1403         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:
    321                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.net.ConnectException: Call From 67a6fb652a0a/172.23.0.2 to 0.0.0.0:8032 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor7.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:792)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:732)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getNewApplication(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.getNewApplication(ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.java:221)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.getNewApplication(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.getNewApplication(YarnClientImpl.java:219)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.createApplication(YarnClientImpl.java:227)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:509)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:714)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:495)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:712)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2900(Client.java:375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1528)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1451)
    ... 28 more
```

I assumed that I need to configure the yarn-site.xml file or other configuration files in the same folder, but I'm not sure. Is it possible to know exactly where the error lies?

Comment: Typo? `conf.get('spark.master')` by itself doesn't do anything. You need to give that to the Session builder.. But what are you setting as `spark.master`? Do you actually have a running Spark-Master Docker service? That docker image does not use YARN, by default...

Comment: @OneCricketeer I haven't explicitly set Yarn. I assumed there was a default configuration in the image I am using. I actually have a spark-master service, but I'm not sure if it communicates properly with the other services. The source code is a simple example copied from the reference guide present in this link https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/stable/user/spark/pyspark.html.
Should I first insert a Yarn image into my stack?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I don't know if it's important to pinpoint the problem, however the commands in the PySpark shell are executed correctly.

Comment: 8032 is a port used by the YARN ResourceManager. So, yeah, you'll need to reconfigure your Spark Master, such as `master=spark://spark-master:7077` in your configure function... Also, I dont think the latest version of that jupyter image uses Scala 2.11, so you may need to update your GeoMesa JAR

Comment: @OneCricketeer The choice to use an older image is deliberate, as they explicitly asked me to reuse an old Dockerfile, already configured with certain versions of the various tools.
I had guessed that the problem could be YARN, but it is not clear to me which configuration function you mean. The one in the source code I showed above, the one in the Docker Compose stack, or the one in the geomesa_pyspark source?

Comment: I apologize if I ask trivial questions, unfortunately I am a beginner with these tools.

Comment: I've never used Geomesa. Version should not matter. Please see https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/specifics.html#standalone-mode-in-python